# Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have set up elasticsearch with password protected, and i am successfully able to work with elastic search by entering username=elastic and password=mypassword

but now I am trying to import mysql data into elasticsearch using logstash, when i run logstash using below command it gives error.
am i missing something?

```
logstash -f mysql.conf
```

[image]

**logstash-plain.log**

```
[2019-06-14T18:12:34,410][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-06-14T18:12:34,424][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.1.0"}
[2019-06-14T18:12:35,400][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 16, column 23 (byte 507) after output {\r\n    elasticsearch {\r\n\thosts => \"http://10.42.35.14:9200/\"\r\n    user => elastic\r\n    password => pharma", :backtrace=>["D:/softwares/ElasticSearch/Version7.1/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:41:in `compile_imperative'", "D:/softwares/ElasticSearch/Version7.1/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:49:in `compile_graph'", "D:/softwares/ElasticSearch/Version7.1/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2577:in `map'", "D:/softwares/ElasticSearch/Version7.1/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:10:in `compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:151:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:47:in `initialize'", "D:/softwares/ElasticSearch/Version7.1/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:23:in `initialize'", "D:/softwares/ElasticSearch/Version7.1/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in `execute'", "D:/softwares/ElasticSearch/Version7.1/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:325:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2019-06-14T18:12:35,758][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2019-06-14T18:12:40,664][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

**mysql.conf**

```
# file: contacts-index-logstash.conf
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://52.213.22.96:3306/prbi"
        jdbc_user => "myuser"
        jdbc_password => "mypassword"
        jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-6.0.5.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from tmp_j_summaryreport"    
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://10.42.35.14:9200/"
    user => elastic
    password => myelasticpassword 
    index => "testing123"
    }
    stdout { codec => json_lines } 
}
```

**logstash.yml**

```
# Settings file in YAML
#
# Settings can be specified either in hierarchical form, e.g.:
#
#   pipeline:
#     batch:
#       size: 125
#       delay: 5
#
# Or as flat keys:
#
#   pipeline.batch.size: 125
#   pipeline.batch.delay: 5
#
# ------------  Node identity ------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
# node.name: test
#
# If omitted the node name will default to the machine's host name
#
# ------------ Data path ------------------
#
# Which directory should be used by logstash and its plugins
# for any persistent needs. Defaults to LOGSTASH_HOME/data
#
# path.data:
#
# ------------ Pipeline Settings --------------
#
# The ID of the pipeline.
#
# pipeline.id: main
#
# Set the number of workers that will, in parallel, execute the filters+outputs
# stage of the pipeline.
#
# This defaults to the number of the host's CPU cores.
#
# pipeline.workers: 2
#
# How many events to retrieve from inputs before sending to filters+workers
#
# pipeline.batch.size: 125
#
# How long to wait in milliseconds while polling for the next event
# before dispatching an undersized batch to filters+outputs
#
# pipeline.batch.delay: 50
#
# Force Logstash to exit during shutdown even if there are still inflight
# events in memory. By default, logstash will refuse to quit until all
# received events have been pushed to the outputs.
#
# WARNING: enabling this can lead to data loss during shutdown
#
# pipeline.unsafe_shutdown: false
#
# ------------ Pipeline Configuration Settings --------------
#
# Where to fetch the pipeline configuration for the main pipeline
#
# path.config:
#
# Pipeline configuration string for the main pipeline
#
# config.string:
#
# At startup, test if the configuration is valid and exit (dry run)
#
# config.test_and_exit: false
#
# Periodically check if the configuration has changed and reload the pipeline
# This can also be triggered manually through the SIGHUP signal
#
# config.reload.automatic: false
#
# How often to check if the pipeline configuration has changed (in seconds)
#
# config.reload.interval: 3s
#
# Show fully compiled configuration as debug log message
# NOTE: --log.level must be 'debug'
#
# config.debug: false
#
# When enabled, process escaped characters such as \n and \" in strings in the
# pipeline configuration files.
#
# config.support_escapes: false
#
# ------------ Module Settings ---------------
# Define modules here.  Modules definitions must be defined as an array.
# The simple way to see this is to prepend each `name` with a `-`, and keep
# all associated variables under the `name` they are associated with, and
# above the next, like this:
#
# modules:
#   - name: MODULE_NAME
#     var.PLUGINTYPE1.PLUGINNAME1.KEY1: VALUE
#     var.PLUGINTYPE1.PLUGINNAME1.KEY2: VALUE
#     var.PLUGINTYPE2.PLUGINNAME1.KEY1: VALUE
#     var.PLUGINTYPE3.PLUGINNAME3.KEY1: VALUE
#
# Module variable names must be in the format of
#
# var.PLUGIN_TYPE.PLUGIN_NAME.KEY
#
# modules:
#
# ------------ Cloud Settings ---------------
# Define Elastic Cloud settings here.
# Format of cloud.id is a base64 value e.g. dXMtZWFzdC0xLmF3cy5mb3VuZC5pbyRub3RhcmVhbCRpZGVudGlmaWVy
# and it may have an label prefix e.g. staging:dXMtZ...
# This will overwrite 'var.elasticsearch.hosts' and 'var.kibana.host'
# cloud.id: <identifier>
#
# Format of cloud.auth is: <user>:<pass>
# This is optional
# If supplied this will overwrite 'var.elasticsearch.username' and 'var.elasticsearch.password'
# If supplied this will overwrite 'var.kibana.username' and 'var.kibana.password'
# cloud.auth: elastic:<password>
#
# ------------ Queuing Settings --------------
#
# Internal queuing model, "memory" for legacy in-memory based queuing and
# "persisted" for disk-based acked queueing. Defaults is memory
#
# queue.type: memory
#
# If using queue.type: persisted, the directory path where the data files will be stored.
# Default is path.data/queue
#
# path.queue:
#
# If using queue.type: persisted, the page data files size. The queue data consists of
# append-only data files separated into pages. Default is 64mb
#
# queue.page_capacity: 64mb
#
# If using queue.type: persisted, the maximum number of unread events in the queue.
# Default is 0 (unlimited)
#
# queue.max_events: 0
#
# If using queue.type: persisted, the total capacity of the queue in number of bytes.
# If you would like more unacked events to be buffered in Logstash, you can increase the
# capacity using this setting. Please make sure your disk drive has capacity greater than
# the size specified here. If both max_bytes and max_events are specified, Logstash will pick
# whichever criteria is reached first
# Default is 1024mb or 1gb
#
# queue.max_bytes: 1024mb
#
# If using queue.type: persisted, the maximum number of acked events before forcing a checkpoint
# Default is 1024, 0 for unlimited
#
# queue.checkpoint.acks: 1024
#
# If using queue.type: persisted, the maximum number of written events before forcing a checkpoint
# Default is 1024, 0 for unlimited
#
# queue.checkpoint.writes: 1024
#
# If using queue.type: persisted, the interval in milliseconds when a checkpoint is forced on the head page
# Default is 1000, 0 for no periodic checkpoint.
#
# queue.checkpoint.interval: 1000
#
# ------------ Dead-Letter Queue Settings --------------
# Flag to turn on dead-letter queue.
#
# dead_letter_queue.enable: false

# If using dead_letter_queue.enable: true, the maximum size of each dead letter queue. Entries
# will be dropped if they would increase the size of the dead letter queue beyond this setting.
# Default is 1024mb
# dead_letter_queue.max_bytes: 1024mb

# If using dead_letter_queue.enable: true, the directory path where the data files will be stored.
# Default is path.data/dead_letter_queue
#
# path.dead_letter_queue:
#
# ------------ Metrics Settings --------------
#
# Bind address for the metrics REST endpoint
#
# http.host: "127.0.0.1"
#
# Bind port for the metrics REST endpoint, this option also accept a range
# (9600-9700) and logstash will pick up the first available ports.
#
# http.port: 9600-9700
#
# ------------ Debugging Settings --------------
#
# Options for log.level:
#   * fatal
#   * error
#   * warn
#   * info (default)
#   * debug
#   * trace
#
# log.level: info
# path.logs:
#
# ------------ Other Settings --------------
#
# Where to find custom plugins
# path.plugins: []
#
# ------------ X-Pack Settings (not applicable for OSS build)--------------
#
# X-Pack Monitoring
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-logstash.html
#xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: password
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://es1:9200", "https://es2:9200"]
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority: [ "/path/to/ca.crt" ]
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.path: path/to/file
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.password: password
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.path: /path/to/file
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.password: password
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.sniffing: false
#xpack.monitoring.collection.interval: 10s
#xpack.monitoring.collection.pipeline.details.enabled: true
#
# X-Pack Management
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-centralized-pipeline-management.html
#xpack.management.enabled: false
#xpack.management.pipeline.id: ["main", "apache_logs"]
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.username: logstash_admin_user
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.password: password
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://es1:9200", "https://es2:9200"]
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority: [ "/path/to/ca.crt" ]
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.path: /path/to/file
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.password: password
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.path: /path/to/file
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.password: password
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.sniffing: false
#xpack.management.logstash.poll_interval: 5s
#xpack.management.enabled: true
xpack.management.elasticsearch.hosts: "http://10.42.35.14:9200/"
#xpack.management.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
xpack.management.elasticsearch.password: myelasticpassword
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message on the logstash log indicates that there is something wrong with your config file:

```
Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError"
```

The rest of message says that the problem is in your `output` block

```
:message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 16, column 23 (byte 507) after output {
```

Double check your output configuration, it needs to be something like this:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["10.42.35.14:9200"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "myelasticpassword" 
    index => "testing123"
    }
    stdout { codec => "json_lines" } 
}
```